# A/B or canary deployments of Lightbend's Lagom with persistent entities?

Tags: lagom

Is there a way to do A/B or canary deployments with Lagom Persistent Entities?

I'm trying to plan out how we can build and deploy reactive microservices and I like the look of Lagom, but I can't see how we'd roll out new versions as canary or a/b testing releases. It seems like the stateful nature of the persistent entities would make that impossible?

Assuming it's possible, I'd also like to figure out how to use Istio on Kubernetes to deploy and manage these new releases, so any pointers on that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, the Lagom framework and its associated tooling obviates many benefits of service meshes like Istio. Orthogonal to meshes is deployment; that said, there is documentation for deploying Lagom services using Kubernetes using [Lightbend Orchestration](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/lightbend-orchestration/current/).

The docs show an explicit example of [Kubernetes canary deployments](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/lightbend-orchestration/current/kubernetes-deployment.html#canary-deployments).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!